# How can I install mmcv-full in a SageMaker inference endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker, openmmlab

I have tried installing [mmcv-full](https://mmcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/installation.html) with pip in the requirements.txt but it takes too long and the health ping interrupts the process. I also tried installing with mim but I get a backend worker error. How can I install it?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/issues/1925

Comment: Have you tried building your own docker container for the sagemaker model?

Answer (score 0):

try to this.

```
git clone https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv.git
cd mmcv
python -m pip install -e .
```